# why the datepicker value not changing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two datepicker inside a form. When the user select the first date, the min and max date of the second datepicker should be updated( one year from the selection). But in my case the min and max date update only once, when I select date in first datepicker for the first time. But if I change the selection, the second datepicker not revised with the changed value.

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Model Production Date</label>
        <input date-picker1 type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Production Date" ng-model="productionDate">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Next Review Date</label>
        <input date-picker2 type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Next Review Date" ng-model="nextReviewDate">
      </div>
```

Js:

```
.directive('datePicker1', function () {

return function (scope, element, attrs) {

    element.datepicker({
        format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
        todayHighlight: true,
        //startDate: stDate || new Date(),
        //endDate:enDate || new Date(),
        autoclose: true 
    }); 
    scope.$watch('productionDate', function (newVal, oldVal) {

        if(newVal){
            scope['productionDate'] = newVal;
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    });         
};

})  



.directive('datePicker2', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linker,

}

function linker(scope, $element, attrs) {


    scope.$watch('productionDate', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('productionDate===='+scope.productionDate);
        splittedDateString = scope.productionDate.split('/');
        stDate = new Date(splittedDateString[0], splittedDateString[1]-1, splittedDateString[2]);
        enDate = new Date(stDate.getFullYear()+1, splittedDateString[1]-1, splittedDateString[2]);
        console.log("Start Date = "+stDate);
        console.log("End Date = "+enDate);
        $element.datepicker({
            format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate: stDate || new Date(),
            endDate:enDate || new Date(),
            autoclose: true 
        }); 

    });         
};

})
```

Each time I can see the `stDate` and `enDate` value changed but the 2nd datepicker start date and end date is not updating. I am stuck for 2 days. Please help

Comment: Still can't solve the problem. Can any body help?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a value into a directive, an isolate scope is created. You can define how values passed into this directive are treated, by using the scope property of directives.

```
.directive('datePicker2', function () {

    return {
        scope: {
            name: "=",
        },
        link: linker
    }

    function linker (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('productionDate', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log('productionDate===='+scope.productionDate);
            splittedDateString = scope.productionDate.split('/');
            stDate = new Date(splittedDateString[0], splittedDateString[1]-1, splittedDateString[2]);
            enDate = new Date(stDate.getFullYear()+1, splittedDateString[1]-1, splittedDateString[2]);
            element.datepicker({
                format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
                todayHighlight: true,
                startDate: stDate || new Date(),
                endDate:enDate || new Date(),
                autoclose: true
            });
            if(newVal){
                scope['nextReviewDate'] = newVal;
            }
            else{
                scope['nextReviewDate'] = setDate();
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: I can access the values from the second `directives` using dot operator after any changes made to the first field. But only the change is not reflected in the datepicker.

Comment: The problem is now solved. Actually the bootstrap datepicker which I am using for this purpose is not refreshing. Please find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091426/can-not-change-datepicker-parameter-on-change-in-another-datepicker