# Can not change datepicker parameter on change in another datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-datepicker

I have two datepicker inside a form. When the user select the first date, the min and max date of the second datepicker should be updated( one year from the selection). But in my case the min and max date update only once, when I select date in first datepicker for the first time. But if I change the selection, the second datepicker not revised with the changed value.

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Model Production Date</label>
        <input date-picker1 type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Production Date" ng-model="productionDate">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Next Review Date</label>
        <input date-picker2 type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Next Review Date" ng-model="nextReviewDate">
      </div>
```

Js:

```
.directive('datePicker1', function () {

return function (scope, element, attrs) {

    element.datepicker({
        format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
        todayHighlight: true,
        //startDate: stDate || new Date(),
        //endDate:enDate || new Date(),
        autoclose: true 
    }); 
    scope.$watch('productionDate', function (newVal, oldVal) {

        if(newVal){
            scope['productionDate'] = newVal;
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    });         
};

})  



.directive('datePicker2', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linker,

}

function linker(scope, $element, attrs) {


    scope.$watch('productionDate', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('productionDate===='+scope.productionDate);
        splittedDateString = scope.productionDate.split('/');
        stDate = new Date(splittedDateString[0], splittedDateString[1]-1, splittedDateString[2]);
        enDate = new Date(stDate.getFullYear()+1, splittedDateString[1]-1, splittedDateString[2]);
        console.log("Start Date = "+stDate);
        console.log("End Date = "+enDate);
        $element.datepicker({
            format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate: stDate || new Date(),
            endDate:enDate || new Date(),
            autoclose: true 
        }); 

    });         
};

})
```

Each time I can see the `stDate` and `enDate` value changed but the 2nd datepicker start date and end date is not updating. I am stuck for 2 days. Please help

Comment: Hi, wich script do you use for rendering your datepicker?

Comment: would you mind to provide a fiddle?

Comment: Wrap your `$element.datepicker...` in `$scope.$evalAsync(function(){ //date picker });`

Comment: @GangadharJannu I have tried now, But still not updating.

Comment: @Jaay I amd using bootstrap-datepicker1.4

Comment: @sankycse Can you provide a fiddle with your code, it will help a lot.

Comment: ***the min and max date update only once, when I select date in first datepicker for the first time*** because you are **Re**-initializing the datepicker which is previously initialized. I had ran into these kind of issue. Check whether the plugin provides any angular wrapper. If not write a directive which updates `startDate & endDate` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of changes needed.

```
 angular.module("myApp", []);
  angular
    .module("myApp")
    .directive('datePicker1', function() {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.datepicker({
          format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
          todayHighlight: true,
          autoclose: true
        });
        scope.$evalAsync(function() {
          scope['productionDate'] = element.val();
        });
      };
    })
    .directive('datePicker2', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker,
      }

      function linker(scope, $element, attrs) {
        // yyyy/mm/dd 2017/02/07
        var dateRegex = /^(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})$/i,
          matchArr;
        var oneYearFromNow = null;
        $element.datepicker({
          format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
          todayHighlight: true,
          autoclose: true
        });
        scope.$watch('productionDate', function(newVal, oldVal) {
          if (newVal) {
            matchArr = newVal.match(dateRegex);
            // (parseInt(newVal.split("/")[0], 10) + 1) + newVal.slice(4);
            oneYearFromNow = (parseInt(matchArr[1], 10) + 1) + newVal.slice(4);
            $element.datepicker('setStartDate', newVal);
            $element.datepicker('setEndDate', oneYearFromNow);
            $element.datepicker('update');
          }
        });
      };
    });
```

It is working. Have a look at [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/e338znLy/)

---

I'll update my answer with code explanation

Comment: Wow!!! This works absolutely wonderful. Please provide some explanation, I am new to angular. And thank you very much.